# A new kind of optical illusion?

Tags: neuroscience, vision, optical-illusion

By accident, I stumbled over this optical illusion:

[image]

It is not a strong one, and maybe you don't experience it, but I see the size of the circles in the second last row decrease from left to right. I don't see this in all the other rows.

Maybe it's only the illusion of an illusion, but in case it's a real illusion (which you experience, too) I wonder:

> Does it belong to a class of optical illusions which already is quite
> well understood? If so: Under which name and where can I learn more
> about this class of optical illusions? If not so: Has anyone an idea
> how to explain it?

Note that the illusion may depend on the **angle of view**. I have the impression it does but did not investigate it systematically. I also may depend on the **size of the image** - on small displays it might not "work".